# pip version conflict (LooseVersion is right)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have an issue with pip and patched libraries.

Here a test scenario:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
iss = LooseVersion("4.21.0-patch01") >= LooseVersion("4.18.3")
print(iss)  # True
```

4.21.0-patch01 is of course newer that 4.18.3.

However, pip doesn't agree:

> ls-supervisor 3.12.0 requires ls-web-confcreator>=4.18.3, but you have
> ls-web-confcreator 4.21.0-patch01 which is incompatible.

ls-supervisor setup:

```
from sys import platform
    
__version__ = '3.12.0'
    
install_requires = [
    'ls-argparser>=1.4.0',
    'ls-cache>=2.1.0',
    'ls-config>=1.0.2',
    'ls-hydra>=4.2.1',
    'ls-logging>=1.2.1',
    'ls-stacktrace>=1.1.3',
    'ls-web-confcreator>=4.18.3',
    'apscheduler',
    'supervisor==4.0.3',
]
```

Does someone have an explanation for that? How is that possible?

EDIT: ls-web-confcreator 4.21.101 for example would have worked, so it has something to do with the -patch convention.

Comment: Might have to do something with anything with a suffix being considered a prerelease version. You may need to add `--pre`...

Comment: unfortunately not, I added --pre to the pip install command and the message is the same

Comment: Oh I got it: ls-web-confcreator-4.21.0.post1 works.  ls-web-confcreator-4.21.0.1 works too